# "Object expected" when calling "dropdown()" in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7

The following code works in Firefox but in Internet Explorer it returns error "Object expected".

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   dropdown("navigation", "auto")
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="navigation">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="hhdh/"><span>Home</span> </a></li>
     <li><a href="hhdh/"><span>All</span> </a></li>
      <ul> 
           <li><a href="sss/"><span>submenu</span> </a></li>
           <li><a href="sss/"><span>submenu</span> </a></li>
     </ul>
  </ul>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I cannot find documentation for the function dropdown anywhere.

Comment: Can we have the source for `dropdown`, please?

Comment: *"cannot find documentation for the function dropdown anywhere."* - Where did you get the idea of using `dropdown` then?

Comment: 'code works in Firefox".What does it display ?

Comment: Ok this one was odd, as you said dropdown is not a standard function, the reason I got to believe that is that dropdown worked in firefox and not in IE7. However I realized there was another script doing some strange url rewriting which worked only on firefox and pointed to the dropdown definition file. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have a standard function called dropdown() so even if Firefox happened to have implemented one it is not going to be widely available.  You would need to include a script with drop down code before calling the function.

If you're looking for a good js drop down menu plugin then check out [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples).

Answer (score 2):

It's a function call and the function is missing.

Comment: I just realized it is a function defined in a file which firefox loads and IE7 doesn't due to some strange url rewriting script in the page.